# Test multiple React component state changes using Test Renderer

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

The component that I am trying to test is having state `isSubmitting` which is set true when we try to submit the form and then it is set back to false when we receive the response from server.

I want to test the state of component after each state update.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState();

  const handlePress = async () => {
      setIsSubmitting(true);
      await submitForm();
      setIsSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onPress={() => this.handlePress} />
      {isSubmitting && <IsSubmitting />}
    </>
  )
}
```

I am able to test only the first component state eg. when I update isSubmitting to true.

```
import React from 'react';
import { act, create } from 'react-test-renderer';
import Component from './Component';

it('shows loading screen after submit, and hides it after', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(form, 'submitForm').mockResolvedValue();

  const wrapper = create(<Component />);

  act(() => {
    wrapper.root.findByType(Button).props.onPress();
  });

  expect(wrapper.root.findByType(IsSubmitting)).toBeDefined();
});
```

How can I check that the IsSubmitting component is hidden afterwards? I am also getting an error for not wrapping update into act().

```
  console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:104
    Warning: An update to Component inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#act
        in Component
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to call act function twice. For the first time without await and for the second time with async await.

```
  const wrapper = create(<Component />);

  act(() => {
    wrapper.root. findByType(Button).props.onPress();
  });

  expect(wrapper.root.findByType(IsSubmitting)).toBeDefined();

  await act(async () => {});

  expect(wrapper.root.findAllByType(IsSubmitting)).toStrictEqual([]);'
```

This way, I am able to test component in both states.